# Dereference works with ptr->operator*() but not with *ptr

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dereference

I'm creating an iterator for a list class.  The iterator has a dereference operator:

```
    T& operator*() const {
        return this->currentNode->data;
    }
```

While trying to use the iterator:

```
for( ; list->begin() != list->end; (*list_iter).operator++())
{
    cout << list_iter << endl;
    cout << list_iter->operator*() << endl;
    //cout << *list_iter << endl;  //not working
}
```

The commented line says "invalid operand to binary experssion ostream and MyList::iterator".  Likewise, if I change from (*list_iter).operator++() to list_iter++ or (*list_iter)++, I get a similar error.

What I think is happening is something like this:

```
int num1 = 3;
int *num2 = new int;
*num2 = 3;
```

In this case, num1 is == *num2...  *num2 is functionally similar to num1 (both are integers), though num2 is a pointer to an integer, the *num2 makes it an integer.

So in:

```
MyList list1();
MyList *list2 = new MyList();
```

In this case, should I expect "*list2" to be similar to list1 in the same way that "*num2" is similar to num1?  Is *num2 going to call a dereferencer, or try to turn a MyList* into a MyList?

Really struggling with what's going on under the hood here.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to include a small, complete code example.  From what you have posted, it is not clear what is going awry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is completely wrong.

The `begin()` iterator is not being saved to `list_iter`, it is being compared directly to the `end()` iterator.  So the loop will run forever if the list is not empty.

`(*list_iter).operator++()` dereferences the iterator to access its data, then calls `operator++` on that data, not on the iterator itself.

`cout << list_iter` is not defined for iterators.  You need to dereference the iterator so you can output the data being referenced: `cout << *list_iter`.

`cout << list_iter->operator*()` dereferences the iterator to access its data, then calls `operator*` on that data, not on the iterator itself.

Your loop should look more like this instead:

```
for(list_iter = list->begin(); list_iter != list->end(); ++list_iter)
{
    cout << *list_iter << endl;
}
```

Or, in C++11, you can use a [range-for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead and let it handle the iterator for you:

```
for(auto &data : *list)
{
    cout << data << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The overloaded `operator*` will only go in effect if you use it directly on an object of the class you defined it on. It has no effect on pointers to such objects. If you use `*` on a pointer, it will just dereference it to the underlying object. Additional `*` would invoke the overloaded `operator*`.

```
MyIterator *iter = new MyIterator();
*iter;  // This will only dereference the pointer.
**iter; // This will dereference the pointer and call your operator*.
```

In your case the `ptr->operator*()` works, because the `->` already does the first dereference. It is equivalent to `(*ptr).operator*()`.

Note that iterators are usually used by-value, you will rarely find them behind a pointer.